# How to generate normal distributed multidimensional points

Tags: r, random, vector

I need to generate a random multidimensional clustered data. For this I want to generate few uniform distributed multidimensional points (centers) and then many normal distributed points around each of them. How can I set the vector (multidimensional point) as mean for the normal distribution? I see the function `rnorm` can get vectors as `mean` and `sd` parameters, but I really don't understand how it works.

Comment: Break the problem down. Do you know how to generate normally distributed points in 1D, with a given mean and sd?

Comment: Yes, sure `rnorm(n = number_of_points, mean, sd)`

Comment: To see the use of vectors in `mean` and `sd` parameters in `rnorm` you can try this: `apply(matrix(rnorm(3000, mean=c(1,2,3), sd=c(1,2,3)), nr=3), 1, sd)` and `apply(matrix(rnorm(3000, mean=c(1,2,3), sd=c(1,2,3)), nr=3), 1, mean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `mnormt`, function `rmnorm()`

```
set.seed(2)
require(mnormt)
varcov <- matrix(rchisq(4, 2), 2)
varcov <- varcov + t(varcov)

rmnorm(1000, mean=c(0,1), varcov=varcov)
```

Comment: The 'MASS' and 'mvtnorm' packages also have similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

Function `rmvnorm.mixt()` in package `ks` is another good alternative. If you install this package and open the vignette file (ks: Kernel density estimation for bivariate data) you can access an example for building a 'dumbbell' density with this function (see page 1). But you can also use the `rmnorm()` function (proposed here already) to build this same density. This can be done as following:

```
xy <- rbind(4/11*rmnorm(200,c(-2,2), diag(2)),  
  4/11*rmnorm(200,c(2,-2), diag(2)),  
  3/11*rmnorm(200, c(0,0),matrix(c(0.8,-0.72,-0.72,0.8),2,2))
)
plot(xy)
```